# Split a text file which has multiple split string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to read a text file which has delimiters of space and as well as double quotes and it is there is not a easy way to identify this scenario, I just wanted to check if this can be achieved using predefined Regular expression otherwise I need to start working on custom split

Here is the string

> "myfile-one two" "1" 3 1453454.00 -134557.63 585.0   24444.8 -999   "NULL" "" 45.60  "" 67°32'5.23455"N 54°56'65.3454"W "NULL" 6.00

The output should be

```
myfile-one two
1
3
1453454.00
-134557.63
585.0
24444.8
-999
NULL
45.60

67°32'5.23455"N
54°56'65.3454"W
NULL
6.00
```

below code try to first split into space delimiter and this split even within the double quotes as well and made as separate entry

```
char[] space = new Char[] { ' ' };

string[] data = comp.Split(space, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Your input is correctly formed, with terms containing spaces in double quotes.  My guess is that a tool which would read this in (e.g. Excel or a database) would use a rudimentary parser to digest everything, rather than a pure regex solution.

Comment: Try `var results = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<!\S)""(?<o>.*?)""(?!\S)|(?<o>\S+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["o"].Value)`

Comment: That is true, this string contains custom output and parsing using regex is may not be easy

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , WOW this is amazing, It simple works... great and many thanks you saved my day... Just curious can you explain on how it is done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may match any substrings between double quotes that are not enclosed with whitespaces and capture what is inside them into a named group, or match any 1+ non-whitespace chars and capture into the indentically named group and use

```
var results = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<!\S)""(?<o>.*?)""(?!\S)|(?<o>\S+)")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Groups["o"].Value)
                .ToList();
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5CS%29%22%28%3F%3Co%3E.*%3F%29%22%28%3F!%5CS%29%7C%28%3F%3Co%3E%5CS%2B%29&i=%22Agate-H6%20raw%22%20%221%22%203%201599744.00%20-172747.63%2095.0%209283.8%20-999%20%22NULL%22%20%22%22%2022.60%20%22%22%2028%C2%B011%278.6223%22N%2092%C2%B034%2730.8887%22W%20%22NULL%22%206.00).

**Pattern details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a whitespace or start of string is required immediately to the left of the current location
- `"` - a double quotation mark
- `(?<o>.*?)` - Group "o": any 0+ chars other than newline, as few as possible
- `"` - a double quotation mark
- `(?!\S)` - a whitespace or end of string is required immediately to the right of the current location
- `|` - or
- `(?<o>\S+)` - Group "o": any 1+ non-whitespace chars.

.NET allows the use of the identically named groups inside one regex pattern accumulating the values found into the corresponding memory buffer that you may "collect" via `.Select(m => m.Groups["o"].Value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since regex is impacting performance heavily and the described scenario is quite simple, I would like to offer a short, fast and regex free solution, that makes use of `string` members only. In addition, the regex free approach is by far more readable and more robust.

```
// The escaped input string
var input = @"""myfile-one two"" ""1"" 3 1453454.00 -134557.63 585.0 24444.8 -999 ""NULL"" """" 45.60 """" 67°32'5.23455""N 54°56'65.3454""W ""NULL"" 6.00 ";

List<string> cleanedInputTokens = input
  .Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Select(token => token.Trim('"'))
  .ToList();
```

The algorithm first splits the input into tokens and then trims leading and trailing specified characters. Because [`Split(Char[], StringSplitOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.Split);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) and [`Trim(Char[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.Trim);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) both accept an array of characters, this pattern is also extensible and flexible.